# matlab cftool iLicense error

Tags: matlab, curve

I am new to matlab. Everytime I try use cftool, it comes with the following error

```
Error using iLicenseCheck (line 228)
The function SFTOOL requires Curve Fitting Toolbox.

Error in C:\Program\Files\MATLAB\R2012a\toolbox\curvefit\cftoolgui\private\sftool_v1.p>sftool_v1 (line 40)

Error in cftool (line 148)
   theApplication = sftool_v1( varargin, names);
```

And if I try sftool, then it comes with following error

```
Warning: SFTOOL will be removed in a future release. Use CFTOOL instead.
> In sftool at 34
Error using iLicenseCheck (line 228) 
The function SFTOOL requires Curve Fitting Toolbox.

Error in C:\Program\Files\MATLAB\R2012a\toolbox\curvefit\cftoolgui\private\sftool_v1.p>sftool_v1 (line 40)

Error in sftool (line 49)
h = sftool_v1(varargin, names);
```

I am using it my uni computers, so i doubt it to be any license issues. I need this to work urgent, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Well, do you have Curve Fitting Toolbox? You can use `ver` command to see the list of your toolboxes.

Comment: See http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/curvefit/release-notes.html?searchHighlight=sftool. As of R2011b, `sftool` now opens `cftool` and issues a warning that `sftool` will be removed in a future release.

Answer (score 1):

It is a license issue. You obviously have Curve Fitting Toolbox installed, otherwise it would give you a different error that it didn't know what the commands `cftool` or `sftool` were.

To test if you are licensed for Curve Fitting Toolbox, type

```
>> license('test', 'curve_fitting_toolbox')
```

This will confirm whether you are licensed for the product.

If you're using a concurrent university license, even if you are licensed for Curve Fitting Toolbox, it's possible that you may not be able to check out a license (for example the license may have expired, or all the licenses may be checked out). You may need to talk to your license administrator to determine that.

Don't worry about the warning you get about `sftool` and `cftool` - over the last few versions they have introduced a new, separate `sftool` in addition to the old `cftool`, and then they redesigned it to combine the tools, but you could start that up using either command. Now they're just warning you that in a future version, the combined tool will be started only with the command `cftool`, and `sftool` will be removed.